# D1 criterion ruling out equilibria only via senders?

Tags: signaling, equilibrium

I have a question regarding the D1 criteria. To my understanding the criteria first identifies which type of sender is more likely to deviate. Then it establishes that a deviation reasonably comes from that type. Then, it sees whether the equilibrium payoffs of that type are dominated given the off equilibrium beliefs that he is deviating and the subsequent best response from the receiver. If this is the case, then the D1 criterion rules out the equilibria.

My question: it seems that the D1 focuses on senders, what happens if the receiver wants to deviate given those reasonable off-equilibrium beliefs? Would the D1 criteria rule out the equilibrium?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: D1 is all about the beliefs of the receiver, it is not focused on the sender at all.

Comment: Some context would be helpful.  You seem to be talking about [divine equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_equilibrium) in a signalling game